Free / Open Source PDF reader that allows commenting by text, drawing and image
tl;dr
I need a new PDF reader to work with. Here are the requirements:

The license must be free (or else, as per company policy, I would have to hand over the licensing to the company). If it's Open Source, that's a bonus
It must work on Windows 10 and 11 as our company is slowly migrating to 11. Linux is a bonus (I use Ubuntu at home).
It must allow drawing shapes to highlight blocks of content
It must allow adding text commentary (not notes that stay hidden until you open them, but text that would show up for example when printing)
It must allow adding pictures with transparency to the document
It must allow selecting text
Stamp creation based on images is a bonus

Whole picture
Foxit PDF had been my go-to PDF reader for probably over a decade now. But I'm honestly tired of having to dodge the malicious installation of paid software through fake updates.
The trigger for this decision though is that I noticed some features were removed recently (probably moved to their paid program) including one that I really need, which is commenting with an image. It's still possible to paste from clipboard, but transparencies become black instead of transparent. If I didn't need transparencies, that would have been fine :/
I'll try to see what version removed this to downgrade to in the meantime
